# Emacs open files from a filename list

Tags: emacs

I have a largish tex project that is separated into several tex files. Everytime I want to work on it I open emacs and manually `C-x C-f` all the files that I want to work on.

I was wondering if there is a way to open files (from command line) from a file containing a list of filenames, something like

filelist.txt:

```
file1.tex file2.tex file3.tex
```

then do

`cat files | emacs -nw`

except that emacs doesn't support the command used as it doesn't like that stdin is reassigned.

any ideas?

Comment: Check out [emacs client](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) so you don't start a new emacs every time, but simply open the files in an already running  emacs.

Answer (score 5):

Pass it through xargs instead:

```
cat files | xargs emacs
```

`xargs` takes text from stdin and passes it as arguments to the program specified. Piping the `files` file into is causes it to call emacs something like:

```
emacs file1.tex file2.tex file3.tex
```

Comment: This answer was my first inclination. At least on Ubuntu 20.04, I get the same error.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Collin Hockey's suggestion is to use command substitution in your shell. The following syntax works in Bourne like shells (`sh`, `bash`, `zsh` &c.).

```
emacs $( cat files )
```

or equivalently (but less readably and more ambiguously)

```
emacs ` cat files `
```

Still not an elegant solution, though. I'm not generally an `emacs` user, but I guess some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847962/what-alternate-session-managers-are-available-for-emacs/849180#849180) might be what you really want. Have a look!

**PS**
Neither mine nor Collin's solution will work properly if the list of filenames is longer than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes. On my system that is approximately 2 MiB.

Answer (score 1):

This really wont solve your issue but will be a potential alternative. Check out `desktop-save-mode` If you have certain buffers open when you close emacs, on reopening emacs it will reopen all of the buffers you had.